# Remove 'Google Chrome' folder on Google Docs

Tags: google-chrome, sync, bookmarks, google-docs

I used to sync my Chrome bookmark, and Chrome create a folder named `Google Chrome` in my Google Docs

Now I want to delete it. Is there any way to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an [active discussion](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=68b132f5870a3cec&hl=en) on the Google support forums right now with one suggestion that has worked for some, but not from all. Quote:

> I just found solution. I created new folder and kept default name "New Folder" then I selected the folder "Google Chrome" and clicked move to and moved it to "New Folder" then I selected "New Folder" and clicked delete

Comment: +1 and accept. It works for me. Maybe it did not work in case this account have an active bookmark syncing

Comment: This doesn't work. "False Alarm---when I go back to my Google Docs it magically appears again right where it was before I tried anything"

Answer (score 1):

Correct Solution:

1. Enable Sync
2. Backup All Bookmarks to local Bookmark file Via : Tools>Bookmark Manager >Export bookmark
3. Delete all Bookmarks from Your machine (chrome: tools>bookmark Manager>bookmark toolbar, Ctrl + A , Delete. Repeat for "Other bookmarks")
4. Wait 2-3 Minutes
5. check Google docs - bookmarks gone :)
6. Restore your exported Bookmarks using Import feature.